# What is the best way to manipulate a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript Object:

```
["campaign_id","campaign_name","campaign_type","campaign_status"]
```

I want the object to look like this:

```
[
  {"name":"campaign_id","title":"campaign_id"},
  {"name":"campaign_name","title":"campaign_name"},
  {"name":"campaign_type","title":"campaign_type"},
  {"name":"campaign_status","title":"campaign_status"}
]
```

What is the best way to manipulate an object using Javascript?

Comment: You have an array and you want to use map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) in Javascript

```js
    var result = ["campaign_id","campaign_name","campaign_type","campaign_status"].map(a => (
          {
            title: a, 
            name: a
          }
    ));

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: This could be streamlined further if you use the short return syntax. E.g.: `[].map(a => ({title: a, name: a}))`.

Comment: Cool !!! I updated :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
var oldArray = ["campaign_id","campaign_name","campaign_type","campaign_status"]

var newArray = oldArray.map((item) => {
    return {"name": item, "title": item}
})
```